# Getting ClientSessionFactory for HornetQ using InVMConnectorFactory

Tags: hornetq

I am trying to run one of the samples provided in HornetQ 2.14 Final User manual. Below is the java code I am executing in a Servlet (Client and Server both are in same VM)....

```
    TransportConfiguration transportConfiguration = new TransportConfiguration(InVMConnectorFactory.class.getName());

    ServerLocator locator = HornetQClient.createServerLocatorWithoutHA(transportConfiguration);

    ClientSessionFactory factory = locator.createSessionFactory(); //Causing error
```

[Java code used to create ClientSessionFactory]

Below is the configuration in **standalone-full.xml**...

```
<acceptors>
   <netty-acceptor name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>

   <netty-acceptor name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
    <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
    <param key="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
    </netty-acceptor>

   <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
</acceptors>
```

[Standalone-full.xml]

**Unfortunately locator.createSessionFactory() is throwing following exception** -

WARN  [org.hornetq.jms.server.recovery.HornetQXAResourceWrapper] (Periodic Recovery) Can't connect to any hornetq server on recovery
 [XARecoveryConfig [hornetQConnectionFactory=HornetQConnectionFactory [serverLocator=ServerLocatorImpl 
 [initialConnectors=[org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-invm-InVMConnectorFactory?server-id=0], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null],
 clientID=null, dupsOKBatchSize=1048576, transactionBatchSize=1048576, readOnly=false], username=null, password=null]]

**ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) HornetQException[errorCode=2 message=Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]**

ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:774)

ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at test.jms.JMSReceiver.receive1(JMSReceiver.java:150)

ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at 
test.jms.JMSReceiver.doGet(JMSReceiver.java:48)

ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)

ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) .... Continued

Not sure how relevant is this but while debugging the source code I found that

```
  public class InVMConnector implements Connector
  {
       public static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(InVMConnector.class);

   public InVMConnector(final Map<String, Object> configuration,
                    final BufferHandler handler,
                    final ConnectionLifeCycleListener listener,
                    final Executor closeExecutor,
                    final Executor threadPool)
      {
         this.listener = listener;

        id =    ConfigurationHelper.getIntProperty(TransportConstants.SERVER_ID_PROP_NAME, 0, configuration);
  //Value of id = 0 in my case
        this.handler = handler;

        this.closeExecutor = closeExecutor;

         executorFactory = new OrderedExecutorFactory(threadPool);

         InVMRegistry registry = InVMRegistry.instance;

         acceptor = registry.getAcceptor(id);
     //acceptor is null here for me
       }

    }
```

[Copied from Source code for Hornetq - 2.14 Final]

Since  acceptor = registry.getAcceptor(id) is null for me it's not trying to create connection with server at all.

Could you please let me know if I am missing any configuration for acceptors?

Thanks in advance for all your help.

With regards,
-ak

Comment: I found the InVMRegistry (singleton) class is loaded twice!!... first time on server start-up and it loads the acceptors in registory. When the webapp is trying to get a InVMRegistry.instance, the InVMRegistry class is loaded again giving a different instance (not one which got loaded by server on startup). So Acceptors are null....

Comment: Please mention 1. which sample you are trying to run; 2. how you are trying to run the sample.

Comment: Also, consider running the samples from `2.3-CR2`. (i.e. there is a new major release about to come out). All examples have been Mavenized, so other than having to install `hornetq-maven-plugin` locally, it should be simpler to run the samples.

Comment: Hi Francisco...Thanks for comments...recently I found the solution...actually I haven't added the HornetQ module as dependency to my War so InVMRegistry (earlier loaded) class was not visible to my war so it was loading again...I am using JBOSS 7